# magento :: change orders from pending to complete

Tags: php, magento

i made a magento module to handle my bank vpc system, all good until now, i'm using Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc as a parent. the code is working 100% but now, when orders take place i see them in the admin panel with "pending" status, i want to mark the request as "complete" when a user submits the request. i tried everything i can think of with no hope.

thanks in advance

Comment: Does your payment method have it's `capture` method called? If so, is that the part where it fails to set a "complete" or "approved" status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at here:- [**Magento: How to change order status programmatically?**](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-change-order-status-programmatically/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: how to change order status to complete from admin panel?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
```

/*

```
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_COMPLETE        = 'complete';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
```

*/

```
$orderId = '100000001';

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($orderId);

$order->setState (Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true);

$order->save();

echo "<br />Status Updated";
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

In Magento ver. 1.12.0.2 if you try to force the order state to Complete, you get the following error:

> The Order State "complete" must not be set manually.